# write input from user in binary file

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, binaryfiles, fwrite

I'm trying to take input from user and write it into binary file. This is my code, it runs smoothly but when I try to read the file in another program the file wont open (shows that its NULL) so I'm not sure why the data is not being saved into the file.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int length=2, width=2;

struct LandData
{
    int height;
};

struct LandData* WritingData()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    struct LandData *arr = (struct LandData*)malloc(length* width* sizeof(struct LandData));

    if ((fptr = fopen("data.bin","wb")) == NULL){
       printf("Error! opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length ; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            printf("choose height: ");
            scanf("%d", &(arr + i*width + j)->height);
            fwrite(arr, sizeof(struct LandData), 1, fptr);
        }
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    return(arr);
}

int main()
{
    struct LandData *arr =WritingData();
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

this is the code for the reading part:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int length =2 , width =2;

struct LandData
{
    int height;
};

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    struct LandData *arr = (struct LandData*)malloc(length* width* sizeof(struct LandData));

   if ((fptr = fopen("data.bin","rb")) == NULL){
       printf("Error! opening file");
       exit(1);
   }

    while(fread(arr,sizeof(struct LandData),1,fptr))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length ; i++) {
            printf(" %d| ", i);
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            printf(" %d ", (arr + i*width + j)->height);
            printf("\n");
        }

        if(fclose(fptr)!=0)
        {
        perror("Error on file closing after reading");
        exit(2);
        }
    }

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*another program the file wont open*". Please show that code.

Comment: `fwrite(arr, sizeof(struct LandData), 1, fptr);` That only writes out a single entry of the array and it is always the first entry.

Comment: If you want to read the file in program like a "text" editor, save the data as text. For example using `fprintf`.

Comment: Cal `perror` when the `fopen` fails to get a more specific error msg.

Comment: @kaylum how do I make it write more than a single entry?

Comment: See the `1`? Well that means one entry. So change that to be the number of entries you want to write. And it doesn't need to be in the loop. Just do the full array write once outside the loop. If you leave it in the loop then you need to keep the one entry but you need to change it so it writes the entry that was just filled in and not the same entry every time. But that would be unlikely to be causing the `fopen` to fail in the reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(fread(arr,sizeof(struct LandData),1,fptr))
```

replace this with

```
while(fread(arr,sizeof(struct LandData),1,fptr) != EOF)
```

Take care EOF its not 0, or false or NULL, it is a value
you can try this by doing something like this

```
if(EOF){
   printf("something")
}
```